# What does the error message "subset must be logical" mean when I want to fit a time series model?

Tags: r, time-series

I want to compute a time series regression in R and convert every variable as ts. Thereby my DV is diff_gap and I have several IVs. Below you see some cutouts of my code:

```
ts_gap <- stats::ts(final_data$diff_gap, start = lubridate::decimal_date(as.Date("2020-08-25")), frequency = 49)
ts_date <- stats::ts(final_data$date, start = lubridate::decimal_date(as.Date("2020-08-25")), frequency = 49)
ts_ht_b <- stats::ts(final_data$hashtags_b, start = lubridate::decimal_date(as.Date("2020-08-25")), frequency = 49)
```

My first question is: When I convert the "date" variable to a ts, why does it look like this and why there are not dates or is it normal?
[1] 18499 18500 18501 18502 18503 18504 18505 18506 18507 18508 18509 18510 18511 18512 18513 18514
[17] 18515 18516 18517 18518 18519 18520 18521 18522 18523 18524 18525 18526 18527 18528 18529 18530
[33] 18531 18532 18533 18534 18535 18536 18537 18538 18539 18540 18541 18542 18543 18544 18545 18546
[49] 18547

Then I combinde the ts variables and fit my model with the tslm() function in R:

```
tslm <- stats::ts.union(ts_gap, ts_ht_b, ts_mentions_b, ts_mentions_t, ts_reply_b, ts_rt_t, ts_pos_b, ts_pos_t, ts_neg_b, ts_neg_t, ts_high_b, ts_high_t, ts_low_b, ts_low_t, ts_att_b, ts_att_t, ts_co_b, ts_co_t, ts_ec_b, ts_ec_t, ts_gov_b, ts_gov_t, ts_ra_b, ts_ra_t, ts_jus_t, ts_pers_b, ts_pers_t)
fit_model <- forecast::tslm(ts_gap ~ ts_ht_b, ts_mentions_b, ts_mentions_t, ts_reply_b, ts_rt_t, ts_pos_b, ts_pos_t, ts_neg_b, ts_neg_t, ts_high_b, ts_high_t, ts_low_b, ts_low_t, ts_att_b, ts_att_t, ts_co_b, ts_co_t, ts_ec_b, ts_ec_t, ts_gov_b, ts_gov_t, ts_ra_b, ts_ra_t, ts_jus_t, ts_pers_b, ts_pers_t, data = tslm)
```

and I get the following error message:

error in forecast::tslm(ts_gap ~ ts_gap, ts_ht_b, ts_mentions_b, ts_mentions_t,  :
subset must be logical

My second question is: why does I get this error message and where is the mistake?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Your `tslm()` function call is invalid. Use `?tslm` to get the manual page. After the formula (the bit with the tild ~), the function expects a `data=` argument which you have labeled at the end so that is not the problem, then the function expects a `subset=` argument, but you have provided `ts_mentions_b` and other vectors which do not seem to be valid arguments to the function. You probably need to read `?formula` because your formula has one DV and one IV followed by a lot of other vectors that are not part of the formula.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I just had to write a '+' instead of ',' and then it worked!